# (Adjective) Slipping

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could someone please clarify the exact meaning of **Slipping** in the text below.

> According to Pentland, though, those arguments ignore much of what
>   these devices enable. Tethered mobility might mean more, not less,
>   social grace. You remember everything about your last conversation
>   rather than feeling your way through **slipping** facts. Rather than
>   grasping to recall someone’s name or where you’ve met, these memories
>   are at your fingertips. "You can have a much better social life,"
>   Pentland points out. "I remember your name, your kids’ names. We’re
>   all happier." Wearables can also prevent the multitasking problem
>   posed by the smartphone’s advent. Rather than pulling out a phone and
>   interrupting your conversation, you don’t even need to avert your
>   gaze. "You can actually pay attention to what you’re doing," Starner,
>   of Google Glass, says. "It doesn’t eliminate multitasking, but it
>   makes it much safer."

Comment: A little more context would be nice. Out of context, *slipping* might mean "less than good". It also sounds like a pun (*feeling your way through something slippery*?).

Comment: @DamkerngT. As always thank you :) As you asked I eddied the context. I was thinking about something more figurative, like "Elusive".

Comment: _Elusive_ is a very good alternative, I think. The idea of _slipping_ is that you try to grasp the facts, hold on to them, but like slippery objects, they slip away from your mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By consulting a dictionary, you'll see:

> <sub>[Meaning of ***slip*** from Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slip?q=slipping)</sub>
>
> 4.1 *(Of a thought or **fact**)* fail to be remembered by (one’s mind or memory); elude (one’s notice)

The phrase "slipping facts" simply means that the facts are moving away from your mind as opposed to "memories .. at your fingertips" or "remember[ing] everything about your last conversation".

Comment: Thank you helix :) I checked it with my favorite dictionaries but found nothing. I thought it might be an unusual figurative way to say "elusive".